# New contributor to Academia, inquiring about if discussing studying methods are fair game

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness

I am new to this site, and as such, I would like to inquire on whether questions about studying and studying methods, in general, are fair game on this website. (I cannot ask a question on Meta yet, as this is my first question on this site.) If not, I would like to know where you can ask these questions. Much appreciated!

Comment: Study methods are very individual, so there is not a ‘right’ answer.

Comment: @JonCuster: While many questions on this topic may suffer from this problem, there are certainly questions that are sufficiently narrowed down or objective, e.g. “What are the pros and cons of Method *X?”*

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help! Have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

In principle they can be on-topic. However, you will need to take care when framing your question, because:

- Undergraduate issues are off-topic
- Questions whose answers are a matter of opinion are not allowed
- Questions whose answers depend very much on an individual or their circumstances are not allowed (because they wouldn't be useful to others)

Comment: Agree, though for the first bullet, I think our stance is that undergraduate "admissions, life, and culture" are off topic. Most aspects of undergraduate coursework and research are on topic.